# UISlider & UILabels on custom tableviewcell not updating with avaudioplayer until audio is played a second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, uislider

*Background*: I have a UITableView which initially loads a few standard UITableViewCells. When one of these is clicked, the table is reloaded but the cell that was clicked becomes a custom subclass called 'RecordingTableCell', which has 2 UILabels, a UIButton and a UISlider. This works fine at the moment.

When the button is pressed, it causes an AVAudioPlayer to be setup and a sound file to be played. However, the method that does this (`[self setupAudio]`) also gets the 2 UILabels and UISlider so that they can be updated with the progress of the audio (I'm not sure if I am getting them the right way).

When the play button is pressed for the first time, the audio plays but the slider or labels do not change at all. However, after the audio has finished (i.e. once audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying is called), if the play button is pressed again, everything works as it should.

[image: The code running in the simulator]

Here is the code: (sorry for the large block!)

```
...

-(void)setupAudio
{
    //Get path
    recordingPaths = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"recordingPaths"];
    recordedAudioURL = [NSURL URLWithString:recordingPaths[selectedRowIndex.row]];

    NSError *audioError;
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[self recordedAudioURL] error:&audioError];
    player.delegate = self;

    [player prepareToPlay];

    recordingCurrentCell = (RecordingTableCell *)[self.tableView viewWithTag:REC_TABLE_CELL_TAG];

    //The following are subviews of recordingTableCell
    currentTimeLabel = [recordingCurrentCell currentTimeLabel];
    totalTimeLabel = [recordingCurrentCell totalTimeLabel];
    slider = [recordingCurrentCell progressSlider];

    //Setup slider & labels
    slider.maximumValue = [player duration];
    totalTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", player.duration];

    slider.value = 0.0;
    currentTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", slider.value];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    selectedRowIndex = indexPath;
    rowSelected=YES;

    //Update the table so that the row with an indexPath equal to 'selectedRowIndex' becomes a custom subclass of UITableViewCell
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [tableView endUpdates];

    if(!player)
    {
        if(selectedRowIndex.row!=indexPath.row)
        {

            [[self player] stop];
            player=nil;

            //Change button on selected cell to the 'play' image
            [actionButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            //If the NSTimer is still going, invalidate it
            if(timer)
            {
                [timer invalidate];
                timer = nil;
            }
        }
    }
    [self setupAudio];
}

//This is hooked up to the button on the custom tableviewcell
- (IBAction)actionButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    actionButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    if(!player.playing)
    {
        [actionButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;

        [player play];
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    }
    else
    {
        if(timer)
        {
            [timer invalidate];
            timer = nil;
        }
        [actionButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [player pause];
    }
}

//This is connected to the slider on the custom tableviewcell.
- (IBAction)slide:(id)sender
{
    if(player)
    {
        player.currentTime = slider.value;
    }
    currentTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", slider.value];
}


- (void)updateTime:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    if(player)
    {
        slider.value = player.currentTime;
        currentTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", slider.value];
    }
}


- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    if(timer)
    {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }

    [self setupAudio];
    [actionButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I've tried moving some of the bits around and I'm not sure if I'm going wrong with getting the 'RecordingTableCell' subviews in [self setupAudio], or if it's an error with the setting up of the audio player.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think the current /duration time of the player is a double type, you can use the following methods to get it as a string:

```
func getTimeString(from duration:Double) -> String{

        let hours   = Int(duration / 3600)
        let minutes = Int(duration / 60) % 60
        let seconds = Int(duration.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))
        if hours > 0 {
            return String(format: "%:%02i:%02i", arguments: [hours,minutes,seconds])
        }else {
            return String(format: "%02i:%02i", arguments: [minutes,seconds])
        }

    }
```

**Current Time String:**

```
func getCurrentTimeAsString() -> String{

        guard let time = player?.currentTime  else {
            return "00:00"
        }

        return getTimeString(from: time)
    }
```

**Total Time String:**

```
 func getDurationAsString() -> String{

        guard let time = player?.duration  else {
            return "00:00"
        }
        return getTimeString(from: time)
    }
```

**Get Process Value:**

```
 func getProgressValue()->Float{
        var theCurrentTime = 0.0
        var theDuration = 0.0
        if let currentTime = player?.currentTime,let duration = player?.duration {
            theCurrentTime = currentTime
            theDuration = duration
        }
        return Float(theCurrentTime / theDuration)
    }
```

And you need to use a Timer to update the current Time label text, don't forget to stop the timer.

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true, block: {[unowned self] (timer:Timer) in
                self.updateUIWithTimer()
            })

  func updateUIWithTimer(){

        currentTimeLabel.text = getCurrentTimeAsString()

        timeSlider.value = getProgressValue()

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply (+1), I've tested your code in Swift and it works on its own, however, when incorporating it into my original objc I would still get the same error in that it the UISlider & UILabels only respond the after the second play.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure if this is the correct way to go about it (i.e. there might be something more fundamental I'm missing here), but I managed to fix the problem by creating a boolean variable to hold whether it is the first time setting up the AVAudioPlayer for a recording, and if so in the `actionButtonPressed` method, re-instantiate the subviews.